Is there any way to hide objects behind a transparent material?
I am trying to create a "dimension shattering" look, and my approach was to create a transparent cell-fracture to create the cracks through which an emission plane will be visible. But this isn't really working for me.
I've tried with the light paths and transparency node by passing it through a subtract. That creates exactly what I want but in Cycles.
Any suggestions for replicating in EEVEE?




If you mean that you want to see the emissive object only through the transparent object, in Cycles you can use the Input > Light Path node and its Transparent Depth output as factor between a Transparent and an Emissive node

@moonboots - not exactly. I want that when the front object is transparent, the light is not visible. But when the cells "break" away, only then the light starts being visible. Also is it possible in EEVEE? My laptop can't handle cycles

so it's the opposite of what I said? the emission is not supposed to be seen through the transparent objects? It seems like the Light Path doesn't work in Eevee, in that case maybe try something with the Compositor?

just for information: the docu explains, which outputs of the light path node work in cycles only: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html

I guess the opposite of what you said makes sense, yeah. I tried a few stuff with compositor, but it just gets more tedious as its being part of a video and there's too many variables. The camera ray in light path does seem to have some promising results, I'll try with that
